# My comments aren't displaying on the HTML page

Tags: python, django

Hey guys I'm building an auction site and for some reason my comments (a dict called commentQuery) is not displaying on the HTML page.

Anyone see why? I'm sure it's something minor I'm missing.

Thanks! relevant code below:

views.py:

```
def comment(request):
username = request.POST.get("username")
itemID = request.POST.get("itemID")
comment = request.POST.get("comment")
new = Comment.objects.create(username = username, comment = comment, itemID = itemID)
new.save()
commentQuery = Comment.objects.all()
return render(request, "auctions/post.html", { "commentQuery": commentQueries})
```

post.html:

```
    <form name="comment"
          action="/comment"
          method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <input autofocus class="form-control" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Enter Comment">
    <input autofocus class="form-control" type="hidden" name="itemID" value={{p.title}}{{p.price}}>
    <input autofocus class="form-control" type="hidden" name="username" value={{user.username}}>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add Comment">
    {% endif %}
    </form>
{% for commentQuery in commentQueries %}
            <li>{{ commentQuery.comment }} by {{ commentQueries.username }}</li>
{% endfor %} 
        
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You passed the `commentQueries` to the template as `commentQuery`, not `commentQueries`...

Comment: I have both commentQuery.comment and commentQueries.username - neither displays.  I was trying both

Comment: it is not the `{{ commentQuery.comment }}` part that is the problem, it is in the `{% for ... %}` loop the problem starts.

Comment: OK I got it now thanks.  It's only showing the comments when I click the add a new comment button. I have to figure out how to just display the comments when a GET is made.  But I'm not sure how to do that since the action "/comment" is only started when someone clicks on Add comment.

Answer (score 1):

You passed the `commentQueries` to the template under the name `commentQuery`, hence if you write `{% for commentQuery in commentQueries %}`, that will not work. You should pass it as `commentQueries`, or perhaps more convenient `comments`:

```
def comment(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    itemID = request.POST.get('itemID')
    comment = request.POST.get('comment')
    Comment.objects.create(
        username=username,
        comment=comment,
        itemID=itemID
    )
    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'auctions/post.html', { 'comments': comments})
```

In the template you can then render the comments:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    <li>{{ comment.comment }} by {{ comment.username }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

It might however be better to work with a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) to the user model, and *not* to store the username. If you copy the username, and later the user changes their username, you can no longer retrieve user data about that user for example.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: Thanks for all the information - for now I just want to get it working before I add the other stuff - but I will look into that - thank you!  However, I'm trying your method with the comments...I have it exactly as you typed it - and nothing is displaying still.

Comment: You passed to the context `{ 'comments': comments}`, with `comments = Comment.objects.all()`?

Comment: OK i figured out the problem.  It's only displaying the comments after I add a new comment.  I have to figure out a way where it just displays without adding a new comment, too.

Comment: @card51short: you should check `if request.method == 'POST'`, and only in *that* case create a new `Comment`.

Comment: Thanks I get that  part.  But how would i send the comments in a get request?  Comments is never called unless u click the button.  It's difficult to figure out how to pass comments to the post page since it is already being passed another dictionary when the post page is rendering

Comment: @card51short: you will need to add the logic in the *view* function where you display the page. In case of a succesful POST request, you should thus also *redirect* to that page. Often a view that updates entities in a POST request never renders templates. It redirects to a template that then fetches and renders. So I think the part to render comments does not belong in this view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222125/discussion-between-card51short-and-willem-van-onsem).